# App Crash on Simulator after xCode9 update

Tags: ios, xamarin, simulator, xcode9

Please help.

After updating to xCode 9 and Xamarin I started getting this error when launching my app on the simulator (iPhone4s and iPhone 5)

> Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorBridge[1307]: Beginning launch sequence for bundle 'AppName'
>           retryTimeout: 120.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge LaunchRetryTimeout )
>           bootTimeout: 300.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootRetryTimeout )
>           bootLeeway: 120.000000 (default write com.apple.CoreSimulatorBridge BootLeeway )
>           Note: Use 'xcrun simctl spawn booted defaults write   ' to modify defaults in the booted Simulator device.
>       Simulator booted at: 2017-09-27 06:13:45 +0000
>       Current time: 2017-09-27 06:38:43 +0000
>       Within boot leeway: NO
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorBridge[1307]: Launch attempt #0 for bundle 'AppName', have been trying to launch for 0 seconds. Modern launch services = NO
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.F31CDDCE-9C99-49C9-9BDE-2F2C7330CFC1[1288] (UIKitApplication:AppName[0x8c48][1673]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: Äúé
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1301]: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:AppName[0x8c48]': No such process (err 3)
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1301]: Application 'UIKitApplication:AppName[0x8c48]' exited voluntarily.
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorBridge[1307]: Failed to lookup the process ID of AppName after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch.
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorBridge[1307]: Non-FBS error launching 'AppName', will NOT retry. Error was: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "Failed to lookup the process ID of AppName after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch." UserInfo=0x79625e00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to lookup the process ID of AppName after successful launch.  Perhaps it crashed after launch.}
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.F31CDDCE-9C99-49C9-9BDE-2F2C7330CFC1[1288] (UIKitApplication:AppName[0x315b][1674]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: Äúé
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1301]: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:AppName[0x315b]': No such process (err 3)
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1301]: Application 'UIKitApplication:AppName[0x315b]' exited voluntarily.
>   Sep 27 08:38:43 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local SpringBoard[1301]: Unable to deliver -[UIRemoteApplication showTopMostMiniAlertWithSynchronizationPort:] message to port 0: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
>   Sep 27 08:40:24 Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local DTMobileIS[1403]: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

My Supported Architectures are : i386 + x86_64

## More info:

**=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===**

Version 7.1.5 (build 2)
Installation UUID: 7ab56de2-d309-4bf5-99dc-8e8927831737
Runtime:
    Mono 5.2.0.224 (d15-3/14f2c81) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Package version: 502000224

**=== NuGet ===**

Version: 4.3.0.2418

**=== .NET Core ===**

Runtime: Not installed
SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

**=== Xamarin.Profiler ===**

Version: 1.5.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

**=== Xamarin.Android ===**

Version: 7.4.5.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3   (API level 10)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        5.0   (API level 21)
        6.0   (API level 23)
        7.0   (API level 24)
        7.1   (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

**=== Xamarin Inspector ===**

Version: 1.3.1
Hash: cbc48dd
Branch: 1.3-release
Build date: Thu, 21 Sep 2017 19:52:53 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

**=== Apple Developer Tools ===**

Xcode 9.0 (13247)
Build 9A235

**=== Xamarin.Mac ===**

Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

**=== Xamarin.iOS ===**

Version: 11.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 152b654a
Branch: xcode9
Build date: 2017-09-15 02:25:56-0400

**=== Build Information ===**

Release ID: 701050002
Git revision: 7afedcaef8e7542e70e3cf8f9bdb26938b8c0876
Build date: 2017-09-15 08:39:58-04
Xamarin addins: 3262aadf811a18c12eac6742532d052b0139a808
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-3-xcode9

**=== Operating System ===**

Mac OS X 10.12.6
Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
    Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Does Xcode 9 open OK? Can create and launch a template created ObjC or Swift project??

Comment: xCode9 opens 100% fine.
I also made a quick ObjC prog and it works fine.

Comment: What version of xamarin.ios do you have installed?

Comment: I have added more info to the original question.
Also, I have managed to launch the application on an actual iPhone 4s device.

It seems like its just the simulators I mentioned that don't work.

Comment: You need to update to the latest versions, `Xamarin.iOS` has been updated to `11.2.0.4` (`xamarin.ios-11.2.0.4.pkg`) to fix Xcode9/iOS11 issues.

Comment: Awsum thank you so much @SushiHangover, I see that the version you mentioned is still in Beta though so I will wait a while and just use the simulators that work until it is released on the Stable channel.

Comment: @SushiHangover You were 100% correct.
If you want you can Answer the question and I will accept, I just updated to the latest Stable release of Xamarin and now everything works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually how this works is that the Xcode version in your mac system and the xamarin version on your windows device should match.

To see which xcode version matches your xamarin version check here:

https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-15-3-5-with-xcode-9-support/

Comment: Why do I need to make sure these match if I don't build my iOS app on Windows?
And also, I have all the correct versions according to the link you sent.

Comment: Well than this can be a bug you can check it on xamarin's forum for more details, if its a bug they will release a solution soon, for the time being you should install the last stable version you were working on at least that's what i suggest

Comment: The other simulators still work as well as the real devices.
Thank you for your suggestion but I will just work like this until the current beta release moves to stable.
SushiHangover suggested that I update to Xamarin.iOS version 11.2.0.4 but this is still in beta.

Comment: i wouldn't suggest the same things but do what suits you best